# Navigation bar back button custom icon?

Tags: android, navigationbar

Is it possible to change the navigation bar (image bellow for reference) back button icon programmatically? Let's say in a certain moment I'd like to change it to be the arrow down icon (normally used to hide the soft input) then change it back to the default after some user interaction.

[image: navigation bar]

Comment: No. That's totally up to the system and there's no API for developers change it. And unless some custom system does anything different, on AOSP it's only for dismissing keyboard that it ever changes.

Comment: That's what I thought, thank you for the reply. Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a popup window over the soft input and making the soft input "arrow down" button do what I wanted on that pop up window.
To control what the soft input "arrow down" button does I had to create a class that `extends EditText` and override:

`public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`